# Wanna know how to implement %input in SAS Macros?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Can some one help me in using %input macro statement in SAS. I came to know by googling, that %input is a macro statement used to create macro variables.

Comment: Umm. I don't get the question. Usually you create macro variable by `%let var_name= 'Value';` You can do this dynamically too `%let var_name= &another_var;`

Comment: Yes what you said is right. But their is another way for creating macro variable using %input statement. And want to know, how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%INPUT` should only be used in legacy situations.

The documentation, if you read it, states the conditions for use.

> #### Details
>
> The macro processor interprets the line submitted immediately after a %INPUT statement as the response to the %INPUT statement. That line can be part of an interactive line mode session, or it can be submitted from within the Program Editor window during a windowing environment session.

This means you are typing in values from a console or submitting code in the **Program Editor**.  %INPUT will cause an error when submitted from the default Enhanced Editor or to a SAS server.

#### Program Editor

```
%symdel a b c;

%input a b c;
123 456 pqr

%put NOTE: &=a &=b &=c;
--- LOG ---;
30   %input a b c;
31
32   %put NOTE: &=a &=b &=c;
NOTE: A=123 B=456 C=pqr
```

#### Enhanced Editor

```
%symdel a b c;

%input a b c;
123 456 pqr

%put NOTE: &=a &=b &=c;
--- LOG ---;
34   %input a b c;
35   123 456 pqr
     ---
     180
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

36
37   %put NOTE: &=a &=b &=c;
NOTE: A= B= C=
```